La imagen se oculta al poner un enlace con la etiqueta <a>
Qué tal compañeros, tengo un detalle con una sección del código, puse tres imágenes dentro de un "section", las imágenes tienen algunos efectos con css, pero al intentar añadir un enlace en alguna imagen en específico con la tag "a", se desaparecen. Dejo el código como referencia.
<style>
   section
   {
      display: flex;
      width: 96%;
      height: 330px;
   }
   section img
   {
     width: 0px;
     flex-grow: 1;
     object-fit: cover;
     opacity: .8;
     transition: .5s ease;
   }
   section img:hover
   {
     width: 400px;
     opacity: 1;
     filter: contrast(120%);
   }
</style>


<section>    
   <!-- esta imagen ha quedado oculta -->
   <a href="./carpeta/pagina.html"> 
     <img src="./imagenes/img_1.png">
   </a>

   <!-- imágenes visibles -->
   <img src="./imagenes/img_2.png" >
   <img src="./imagenes/img_3.jpg" >
</section>

El detalle es que, intento poner un enlace a cada una de las imágenes, para llevar al usuario a un lugar determinado. Gracias.

Al envolver la imagen con una etiqueta A esta ya no es "hija" de un contenedor flex. De la misma manera al no tener la etiqueta A los efectos de la etiqueta IMG no se comporta igual en el mouse over.
Para este caso particular agregandole a la etiqueta section a un display flex y las mismas reglas que section img el efecto se acerca a lo esperado.
Es conveniente usar class y definir los estilos por clases CSS, como para evitar influir al resto de A del documento.


section {
  display: flex;
  width: 96%;
  height: 330px;
}

section a {
  display: flex;
}

section img,
section a {
  width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

section img:hover,
section a:hover {
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 1;
  filter: contrast(120%);
}
<section>
  <!-- esta imagen ha quedado oculta -->
  <a href="#1">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/200">
  </a>

  <!-- imágenes visibles -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/200//200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/300//200">
  <a href="#2">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/400//200">
  </a>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/500//200">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/600//200">
</section>




Que buen aporte, agradezco tu comentario, era lo que requería. Gracias.
